# Simple almost linear functional equation

Tags: functional-equations

I'd like to solve functional equation:
$f(x+y)=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{1-f(x)f(y)}.$

I've managed to get:
$f(0)=0,f(n)=0$ for all $n\in N$;
$f(\frac{1}{2})=0$;
$f(-x)=-f(x)$.
I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: Hint: think about $\tan(x+y)$.

Comment: As per the above comment, if $k\ne 0$, and if the domain of $f $ is $R$ minus the set of odd multiples of $\pi /2 k$, then $\tan k  x$ is a solution, so I don't see how you can get $f(1)=0$. Is the domain $R$ ? And how did you get $f(1)=0$? Are you assuming $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Without loss of generality, we may look for $f$ in the form of $\tan(g(x))$. Then $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)+\pi n$, which looks less complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to careful in these kind of problems. For example, if we assume $\;f(x):=k\;$ for some constant $k$, then $\;k=0\;$ or $\;k^2=-1\;.$ If we assume
$\;f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n\;$ then solving for the coefficients gives
$\;f(x)=\tan(cx)\;$ for some constant $c.\;$ If $f$ is not assumed to be continuous then there are many "bad" solutions similar to [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). See also [MSE question 423492](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492) for equations related to Cauchy's.